# How do I wrap exception of EitherT into left?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

Imagine I have `OptionT[IO, Value]` like this

```
case class FailureMsg(code: String, ex: Option[Throwable])

val fff: IO[Either[FailureMsg, Int]] = OptionT.some[IO](12345)
  .map { value ⇒
    println("Mapping over")
    value
  }
  .flatMapF[Int](_ ⇒ IO.raiseError(new RuntimeException("err1")))
  .toRight(FailureMsg("Code0", None))
  .recoverWith {
    case ex ⇒ // Not Throwable!
      EitherT.leftT[IO, Int](FailureMsg("Code1", Some(ex)))
  }
  .value
```

How can I catch `err1` and wrap it into `Left[FailureMsg]`. I expected `recoverWith` help me but surprisingly it's alias of `mapLeft`. What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote helper class to do this.

```
implicit class EitherTExt[F[_], A, B](val obj: EitherT[F, A, B]) {
    def recoverThrowable(pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, Either[A, B]])(implicit A: ApplicativeError[F, Throwable]): EitherT[F, A, B] =
      EitherT(obj.value.recover(pf))
  }
```

Let me know if there is more elegant shorter way.

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the types.

```
val start: OptionT[IO, Int] = OptionT.some[IO](12345)

val thenMap: OptionT[IO, Int] = start.map { value ⇒
  println("Mapping over")
  value
}

// here it will get off the rails
val thenFlatMapF: OptionT[IO, Int] =
  thenMap.flatMapF[Int](_ ⇒ IO.raiseError(new RuntimeException("err1")))

val thenToRight: EitherT[IO, FailureMsg, Int] =
  thenFlatMapF.toRight(FailureMsg("Code0", None))

val result: IO[Either[FailureMsg, Int]] = thenToRight.value
```

`thenFlatMapF` won't produce `OptionT[IO, Int]` if `IO.raiseError` is the case, because no default mapping of `Throwable` to what? And you will get exception in folding result of `IO.raiseError`.

First attempt to fix it, will illustrate it:

```
val thenFlatMapF: OptionT[IO, Int] = thenMap.flatMapF[Int](_ ⇒ {
  IO.raiseError[Option[Int]](new RuntimeException("err1")).recoverWith {
    case err =>
      val result: Option[Int] = ???
      IO.pure(result)
  }
})
```

How to handle error in place without breaking `IO` and return `Option` so that `OptionT[IO, Int]` is produced?

So basically, in this case, if you expect `flatMapF` to fail and need information on error, then it is better to have `EitherT` as its container, rather than `OptionT`.

Once done, possible solution shows that at some point `leftMap` or variance should be done to map the `Throwable` to `FailureMsg`. One of reasons is because `IO` has default error expressed as `Throwable`. One can't just mix `FailureMsg` and `Throwable`. Either inheritance is required so that `FailureMsg` is of type `Throwable/Exception`, or mapping should be done of errors in suitable places.

My rough solution would be:

```
val fff: IO[Either[FailureMsg, Int]] = OptionT.some[IO](12345)
  // ok, let's do some input interpretation
  .map { value ⇒
    println("Mapping over")
    value
  }
  // if no input, means error
  .toRight(FailureMsg("Code0", None))
  // if there is interpreted input to process, do it and map the errors
  .flatMapF(_ ⇒ IO.raiseError[Int](new RuntimeException("err1")).attempt.map(_.leftMap {
    case err: RuntimeException if err.getMessage == "err1" => FailureMsg("err1", Some(err))
    // just for illustration, that if you have temptation to map on error,
    // most likely there won't be only exception
    case t: Throwable => FailureMsg("unexpected", Some(t))
  }))
  .value
```

However, normally contents of `flatMapF` would be a separate function or effect that would include error handling. Something like this:

```
val doJob: Int => IO[Either[FailureMsg, Int]] = arg =>
  IO.raiseError[Int](new RuntimeException("err1")).attempt.map(_.leftMap {
    case err: RuntimeException if err.getMessage == "err1" => FailureMsg("err1", Some(err))
    case t: Throwable => FailureMsg("unexpected", Some(t))
  })

val fff: IO[Either[FailureMsg, Int]] = OptionT.some[IO](12345)
  .map { value ⇒
    println("Mapping over")
    value
  }
  .toRight(FailureMsg("Code0", None))
  .flatMapF(arg ⇒ doJob(arg))
  .value
```